# Best Embedded Key-Value Storage

Tags: key-value-store, rocksdb

good people.

Recently we have been faced with this problem.
We need to store lots of (key, value) pairs. But keys are always monotonic. You can consider the keys as a 64 bit integer and we always insert the data in increasing order of keys (you can think of this as some sort of time series).

Also - write happens in batch (let's say in 5 sec interval). But we can read arbitarily and read : write = 200 : 1.

What do you think would be the ideal option for such data ? How can I configure rocksDB optimally?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

RocksDB works better if your key is inserted in increasing order. For example, you can encode your integers in big endian string and store them as RocksDB key.